# GoogleSignin.signIn() return null idToken

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

As in title I am getting null for **idToken** and **accessToken** values while calling the GoogleSignin.signIn()

the code ( it is same as the example from [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/social-auth#Google) :

```
export async function googleLogin() {
    try {
        // add any configuration settings here:
        await GoogleSignin.configure();

        const data = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

The google-services.json file is in place and it worked fine previously. I had some issues with building the app after migrating from react-native 0.59.9 to 0.61.5 , now the apps starts and the main issue are the new values from GoogleSignin

versions of libs:

```
    "@babel/runtime": "7.7.7",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "3.0.3",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-camera": "3.15.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-eject": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "2.0.8",
    "react-native-progress": "4.0.3",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "1.3.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "0.4.2",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "9.13.6",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "1.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-stomp": "4.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your *webClientId* in `GoogleSignin.configure()`.

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
})
```

Also you should not call the `configure` method when the component is calling `signIn()` as the configuration need to be done before you call for `SignIn()`.
Try calling configure outside Component declaration after imports or in **Constructor** or maybe in **useEffect**

Finally, you should take look in updated docs at [Social Authentication Firebase][1]
[1]: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth

I struggled a lot making it work.
Hope it helps for you